# Stale token in Apollo Client subscriptions

Tags: javascript, websocket, jwt, subscription, apollo-client

I have working subscriptions and correct token in http link but I get stale token from the last session in the ws link. When I console log the `connectionParams` handler it gets executed only on page refresh so it's no wonder I get stale token. I thought that it should be executed on every websocket transaction. My server code is ok, I parse tokens without problems. I read the token from local storage the same way I read it for http link. The full code of the client can be found [here](https://github.com/nemanjam/audio-twitter/blob/master/client/src/index.js)

**Here is my websockets link:**

```js
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:8000/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    lazy: true,
    inactivityTimeout: 1000,
    connectionParams: () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      // this console log gets executed
      // only on page refresh
      console.log('token ws', token);
      return {
        headers: {
          'x-token': token ? token : '',
        },
      };
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: You have working client code example here: https://github.com/nemanjam/audio-twitter/blob/master/client/src/index.js and server here: https://github.com/nemanjam/audio-twitter/blob/master/server/src/index.js